# Remote Desktop Connection - Connection Failed

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

Let me explain the problem.

My system is connected to a network and 'was' having XP installed in it. Recently i formatted the system and installed windows server 2003 and added the machine to the network. Everything is working fine like mapping the network drives, pinging the machines etc. But i've the following problems.

- I'm not able to do a remote desktop
  connection to another system in the
  network.
- Some systems in the network is able
  to do a remote desktop to my machine.
  But not all.
- If i host any web service in my
  system i'm not able to connect it
  from any other machine in the
  network.

I've already configured the Remote Desktop to accept connections.

Any ideas?

NLV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments to the answers that have been posted so far, it sounds like you have a name resolution problem. What do you use internally for name resolution, DNS, WINS, broadcast?

Comment: I'm not very good about these things. They are DNS i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

is IPv6 enabled or disabled on that machine?  make sure netstat shows that port 3389 is listening.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Windows Firewall enabled? Check in Services to see if Windows Firewall is started. If so, check out the Windows Firewall control panel to disable and/or change settings.

Comment: This is a network problem. If i use IP it is working correctly. The some of the systems in the network is not resolving the machine name. So i'm using IP for time being.

Answer (score 0):

you have to narrow the scope to define whether this is a machine problem or a network one.

1. what are the errors when a machine
   cannot connect to yours?
2. what are your machine's firewall
   settings?
3. please don't take this as
   condescending, but are you sure
   you're turning up the web services
   properly? i.e., just because you
   have a web site configured doesn't
   mean you've actually turned on IIS
   or Apache (or whatever web server
   you're using)

Comment: I found that my system is able to be pinged from some machines in my network and not from some. So i found this to be a network problem. If i use my machine ip, its working fine. So i'm using it.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you saying that if you use the IP and not the name of your machine, it works all the time? If that's the case, then you are likely dealing with a DNS problem, and not a network one. My guess would be that there are different search lists set up on different machines.